# How can I remove all empty values when I explode a string using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I remove all empty values when I explode a string using PHP for example, lets say a user enters `",jay,john,,,bill,glenn,,,"`?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is part of the code that explodes user submitted values.

```
$tags = explode(",", $_POST['tag']);
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

E.g. via [array_filter()](http://docs.php.net/array_filter) or by using the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY option on [preg_split()](http://docs.php.net/preg_split)

```
<?php
// only for testing purposes ...
$_POST['tag'] = ",jay,john,,,bill,glenn,,0,,";

echo "--- version 1: array_filter ----\n";
// note that this also filters "0" out, since (bool)"0" is FALSE in php
// array_filter() called with only one parameter tests each element as a boolean value
// see http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling
$tags = array_filter( explode(",", $_POST['tag']) ); 
var_dump($tags);

echo "--- version 2: array_filter/strlen ----\n";
// this one keeps the "0" element
// array_filter() calls strlen() for each element of the array and tests the result as a boolean value
$tags = array_filter( explode(",", $_POST['tag']), 'strlen' ); 
var_dump($tags);

echo "--- version 3: PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY ----\n";
$tags = preg_split('/,/', $_POST['tag'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($tags);
```

prints

```
--- version 1: array_filter ----
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "jay"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "john"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "bill"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "glenn"
}
--- version 2: array_filter/strlen ----
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "jay"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "john"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "bill"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "glenn"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
--- version 3: PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY ----
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "jay"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "john"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "bill"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "glenn"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Comment: @VolkerK are you showing me 2 examples because `$tags = preg_split('/,/', $_POST['tag'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` alone works. Thanks!

Comment: @snag: Yes, he was showing two different ways to do it. The `array_filter` method he listed first is probably more standard, but as he mentioned, it could remove values you wanted to keep, so he included the `preg_split` method as an alternative.

Comment: The reason this isn't working for some is because it doesn't handle whitespace. ie.`a,b,c, ,d". For that, I recommend array_filter with a callback.

Comment: If you want to make sure your array is re-indexed then wrap it in `array_values`

Answer (score 4):

```
$tags = array_diff(explode(",", $_POST['tag']),array(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//replace multiple commas
$tags = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $_POST['tag']);
//explode
$tags = explode(',', $tags);
```

Comment: Should be `explode(',', $tags)` and keeps the last empty element for the given string `",jay,john,,,bill,glenn,,,"`.

Comment: still keeps the last empty element ;-)

Answer (score -4):

Simply try:

```
$tags = explode(", ", $_POST['tag']);
```

Adding space after comma, does the job!