# store info and pull out in array

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with a row 'genre' this contains all types of genres for the movie seperated by a space like an example of this would be

```
Animation Comedy Horror
```

They are all different genres so they need to be pulled out of the database and put in an array based on their genres I originally began coding this:

```php
<?
sql = "SELECT moviename,genre FROM movieHosting";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
?>
```

But I soon realized shortly after that every genre is going to be needed to be put in the array seperate if I did

```php
$genreArray = array($row->genre);
```

But this wont work it would generate an array like

```
$genreArray = array("Animation Comedy Horror");
```

But it needs to generate

```
$genreArray = array("Animation","Comedy","Horror");
```

Comment: STOP USING mysql_* ! use mysql**i**_* instead !!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Splitting up a string in PHP with every blank space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020202/splitting-up-a-string-in-php-with-every-blank-space)

Comment: Also see [php explode: split string into words by using space a delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638753/php-explode-split-string-into-words-by-using-space-a-delimiter)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried using the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function?

Something like:

```
$genreArray = explode(" ", $row->genre);
```

Comment: I would recommend this over the preg_split function. Cleaner, simpler to look at and quicker.
On another note, why not normalize your database a little for efficiency with a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: STOP USING mysql_* ! use mysqli_* instead !!

Comment: What @Simon means is you should not be storing multiple pieces of data as one field. Each genre is its own piece of data. If movies can have multiple genres, you should be moving genres out to a separate table with the following fields: `id`, `movie_id`, `genre_name` or similar.

Comment: Then, instead of having to do text processing in PHP, you can just ask the database for e.g. `('SELECT genre_name FROM genres WHERE movie_id = ?', $movie_id)`. This has additional benefits in the long run, for example, allowing you to find all movies in the `Horror` genre very easily.

Answer (score 5):

Here is more close to your logic.

```
$string = 'Animation Comedy Horror';
    $genra = explode(" ", $string);
    print_r($genra); //Array ( [0] => Animation [1] => Comedy [2] => Horror )

    echo $genra[0]; //Animation

    echo '<hr>'; // OR

    foreach($genra as $value){
        echo $value . '<br>';
    }

// Output
Animation
Comedy
Horror
```

Hope our answers brings more clarification to your problem.

Comment: I really like this :) gives a really nice example of what can be done however somebody has already given me what i need an answered it first so all i can give you is an upvote :)

Comment: Thank you for recognizing my answer @Joseph Flames I agree that JamesBlond has the best and simplest answer. ^_^

Comment: i upvote because your answer is correct and to be an SO fanatic :)

Comment: Thanks @HalayemAnis ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Understand these and use accordingly.

```
<?php
    $str = "Animation Comedy Horror";
    $str_arr = explode(' ', $str);
    print_r($str_arr);
    $str_arr = split(' +', $str);
    print_r($str_arr);
    $str_arr = preg_split('/ +/', $str);
    print_r($str_arr);
?>
```

Check This : https://eval.in/532527

Also Understand about,

**explode** :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

**preg-split**  : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

**split** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

split is depricated now.

Answer (score 3):

```
   $result = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "Animation Comedy Horror");
    print_r($result );
    print_r(implode(",",$result));
```

OUT PUT

```
 Array ( [0] => Animation [1] => Comedy [2] => Horror ) 

 Animation,Comedy,Horror
```

Answer (score 3):

**WARNING**
Stop using mysql_* functions, for multiple reasons : completely removed, officially deprecated, ... and for exhaustive list you can read this thread [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/4098311), instead you can use [mysqli_*](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

I think that it is a very bad design to store **genre** like you do it
How you will update your data ?
How to retrieve movies by genre ?

Each simple SQL operation will be a nightmare, instead of this, spend your time to correct your desgin, for example you can simply create a dedicated table from genre

```
ID | type
------------
1  | Comedy
2  | Horror
3  | Mangas
4  | ... 
5  | Animation
```

And create an Entity Table that will associate the movie with **[1, N]** genre

```
MovieId | GenreId
-----------------
2       | 1
2       | 2
2       | 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using PHP's `explode()` function.  This function expects 2 parameters, a delimiter, and a string.  The delimiter should be what you want to look for in the string to separate items.  In practice this would look like:

```
$genreArray = explode(' ', $row->genre);
```

Now `$genreArray` will look something like this (output generated from `var_dump($genreArray)`):

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "Animation" [1]=> string(6) "Comedy" [2]=> string(6) "Horror" }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

1. Through multiple arrays:

   ```
   <?
   $sql = "SELECT moviename,genre FROM movieHosting";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   /* fetched value */
   $moviename = $row['moviename'];
   $genre= $row['genre'];
   ?>
   ```
2. Through single arrays to produce result like `$genreArray = array("Animation","Comedy","Horror");`

   ```
   <?
   $sql = "SELECT moviename,genre FROM movieHosting";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   /* fetched value */
   $array =array();
   foreach($row as $r){
       $moviename = $r['moviename'];
       $genre = $r['genre'];
       $array_push = array_push($array,$moviename,$genre);
       print_r($array_push);
   }
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score -2):

```
$genreArray = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "Animation Comedy Horror");
print_r($genreArray );
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Animation
    [1] => Comedy
    [2] => Horror
)
```

Comment: looks about what I need quick question would this work in the syntax

Comment: $genreArray = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $row->genre); and would it actually store an array inside $genreArray

Comment: Yes it would actually store an array. I especially show you example of what you get by using this function. It will split the phrase by any number of commas or space characters, which include " ", \r, \t, \n and \f

Comment: What's the benefit of using a more expensive regular expression with preg_split() compared to the explode() function? They both do the same in this instance, but explode() is quicker.

Comment: In the PHP manual notes section here [link](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) they say: **Tip**

If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose **faster** (albeit simpler) alternatives like `explode()` or `str_split()`.

Comment: As I wrote this code helps you to avoid some special characters in incoming string. In this particular sample of data to split in array you will not see any changes in productivity or speed.

Comment: I have bad experience using str_split, when once our data providers change an output of there api, and add "," as separator... :)