# How to split the title in the php string to create the html tags link for the post

Tags: php, string, hyperlink, split, tags

I want to create dynamic url with `$title`.

```
$title = "google facebook pikachu";
$tags = $title;
$link = "https://example.com/?";

// Output should be like this

<a href="https://example.com/?google">google</a>
<a href="https://example.com/?google">facebook</a> 
<a href="https://example.com/?pikachu">pikachu</a>
```

Thanks everyone !

Comment: Googling `split string php` shows you nothing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php explode: split string into words by using space a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638753/php-explode-split-string-into-words-by-using-space-a-delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

```
$title = "google facebook pikachu";
$tags = $title;
$link = "https://example.com/?";

foreach( explode(' ', $title ) as $target ){
   echo "<a href='".$link.$target."'>".$target."</a> ";
}
```

Comment: The first time I joined this forum and I was really surprised about the help extremely fast and accurate. Thank you very much ! <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode() function to create an array of the links.

```
$titles = explode(" " , $title);

foreach ($titles as $title) {
  echo '<a href='.$link.$title.'>'.$title.'</a><br />';
}
```

Comment: The first time I joined this forum and I was really surprised about the help extremely fast and accurate. Thank you very much !